# Multidimensional Array with String Variables

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have been having trouble with multidimensional arrays. 
I want to add a user name to the first row then use a second embedded for loop to add a user Id.
I just don't know how to assign it to the user input.

```
int rows = 2;
int cols = 2;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[][] info = new String [rows][cols]; 

for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) 
{
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
   System.out.printf("Please enter name for user %d", row +1);
   info[rows][cols] = input.nextLine();

}
```

I don't know what code I would need to add the user name to the first row.

Example of input:

Please enter name for user 1:  Billy Smith
Please enter name for user 2:  Estelle Geddis

Then for the user id (Have not coded this for loop)

Please enter ID for Billy Smith: bSmithSATX
Please enter ID for Estelle Geddis: eGeddisLACA

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Can you give an example, showing what the user might input, and the corresponding array after you've put the input into the right place?

Comment: Multidimensional array in Java is actually an array of arrays. What do you actually want to store?

Comment: Updated tag & added example.

Comment: @Nandana I want to store the row with two string variables for user name & store two string variables for user id.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional array in Java is actually an array of arrays.

UPDATE: Based on your input specification, I assume this is what you are trying to do. Please read a bit more about multidimensional arrays in a Java textbook.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] info = new String[rows][cols];

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter name for user %d", row + 1);
            info[row][0] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter id for %s", info[row][0]);
            info[row][1] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(info[row]));
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be so much easier to have a class. But unfortunately, it has to be a multidimensional array 2x2. Its an assignment.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer based on the update to your question :)